# Equivalent of SQL JOIN in NSPredicate - Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a SQL Query that works in my SQLite database that I copied from the app. My problem is I don't know how to write it as NSPredicate.

The SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM ZUSERS JOIN ZFEATURES ON ZFEATURES.Z_PK = ZUSERTOFEATURES WHERE ZFEATURES.ZFEATURETOPRODUCTS = myProductPK AND ZFEATURES.ZNAME = 'FEATURE_NAME'
```

Can anyone please guide me to the right direction with NSPredicate to accomplish the same result.

Here's how the model looks like: http://postimage.org/image/1jyc6lidg/

Thanks,
dfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, but not sure if it's correct/best way but I get the output I want.

I use this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(userToProducts == %@ && userToFeatures.name == %@)", product, <FEATURE_NAME>];
```

And fetch for the `Users`'s entity with the predicate above.

I'm happy with it so far...